# How to retrieve user 2nd level resource with nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-resources

I have a user model that has many photos and those photos have many tags.

My routes:

```
resources :users do
  resources :photos do  
    resources :tags
  end
end
```

My view:

```
<%= @user.photos.tags.count %>
```

I don't know how to retrieve all the tags a user has, since it's a 2nd level nested resource. 
Any idea? Thanks guys!

Comment: You can do it this way: `Tag.includes(photos: :user).where(users: { id: current_user.id }).count`

Comment: Isin't that too much logic for the view?

Comment: @MrYoshiji Or is this suposed to be a new scope in the user model?

Comment: Following the Rails Style Guide (https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide), you should never have to write any model's name inside a view. It is very relative, I always use it, but the spirit here is more like "never make a query in the view, do it in the controller". In your case I would create a scope in the User model, something like `scope :tags_through_photos, ->(user) { Tag.includes(photos: :user).where(users: { id: user.try(:id) || user }) }`

Comment: What exactly don't you know: how to construct an URL or just retrieve tags for users?

Comment: Actually since this is going to be used a lot it should either be a method on User model or better a counter cache

Comment: Retrieve tags from users...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :photos
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tags, dependent: :destroy
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :photo
end

# @user.tags
```

Just scroll to the end of http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association.
By the way, don't be confused with nested resources and associations as terms.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :photos
  has_many :tags, through: :photos
end
```

And at the view:

```
<%= @user.tags.count %>
```